# What is the fastest way to get a HTML Content using java?

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedinputstream

I have this, but I was wondering if there is a faster way:

```
        URL url=new URL(page);
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String tmp="";
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        while((tmp=in.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(tmp);
        }
```

Comment: This code uses your system's default character set... which is fine as long as the page content uses the same character set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably network is the biggest overhead, there isn't much you can do on Java code side. But using [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream%29) is at least much faster to implement:

```
String page = IOUtils.toString(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Remember to close underlying stream.

Comment: that is right, the IOUtils method does the same thing in one line except it uses StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder

Comment: +1, this is simple and probably fast enough. If not, I suppose you could read the Content-Length header and pre-allocate a byte buffer exactly the same size as the content, then pass the byte array to a String constructor... but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3):

if you need manipulating with your html, find some library. Like for example [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

Example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache Commons IO's IOUtils as Tomasz suggests, there's an even simpler method: [toString(URL)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.net.URL%29), or its preferred cousins that take a charset (of course that requires knowing the resource's charset in advance).

```
String string = IOUtils.toString( new URL( "http://some.url" ));
```

or

```
String string = IOUtils.toString( new URL( "http://some.url" ), "US-ASCII" );
```